# How do i store key-value information that has variables in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, datastore

I'm creating an app to store tasks. However, I can't find a working solution that stores more than one task.
This is the code I'm running that you should need:

```py
def newtaskwin():
    newtaskwin=Toplevel(todohome)
    newtaskwin.geometry()

    taskbxfrme=tk.Frame(newtaskwin)
    TaskNameLbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='Task Name:').grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
    TaskNameEntry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    TaskNameEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)

    GroupNameLbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='Group:').grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
    GroupNameEntry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    GroupNameEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)

    PriorityLbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='Priority:').grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5)
    PriorityEntry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    PriorityEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5)

    start_date_lbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='Start Date:').grid(row=4, column=0, pady=5)
    start_date_entry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    start_date_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=5)

    end_date_lbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='End Date:').grid(row=5, column=0, pady=5)
    end_date_entry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    end_date_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=5)

    start_time_lbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='Start Time:').grid(row=6, column=0, pady=5)
    start_time_entry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    start_time_entry.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=5)

    end_time_lbl=tk.Label(newtaskwin, text='End Time:').grid(row=7, column=0, pady=5)
    end_time_entry=ttk.Entry(newtaskwin, width=100)
    end_time_entry.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=5)


    def create_task():
        with dbm.open('taskstorage.db' , 'n') as taskdb:
            taskdb['name']=TaskNameEntry.get()
            taskdb['Group']=GroupNameEntry.get()
            taskdb['Priority']=PriorityEntry.get()
            taskdb['Start_Date']=start_date_entry.get()
            taskdb['End_Date']=end_date_entry.get()
            taskdb['Start_Time']=start_time_entry.get()
            taskdb['end_time']=end_time_entry.get()
            messagebox.showinfo('eTasks', 'Task saved')
        
        
    create_task_btn=tk.Button(newtaskwin, command=create_task, width=10, text='Save').grid(row=9, column=0)
```

I tried using json and dbm; json didn't allow me to store the dictionary with variables, dbm overwrote the previous data and json didn't dump the data because of the immutable and mutable data type rules in dictionaries in python.

Comment: pickle them and store them

Comment: First, this has too much tkinter and not enough data to be reproducible. Second - isn't overwriting a file what you want to do? If not, what do you want to do?

Comment: What I want to be able to do is store multiple tasks in the same file, without deleting the previous contents, and be able to call each task separately by name in the main code. Also, how do i make it reproducible?

Comment: _"how do i make it reproducible?"_: See [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON files cannot be appended to [afaik] without loading the previous data and then updating with new data before saving again [so, the file *will* be over-written, but since the old data was loaded, it will be saved again but with the addition of the new data]. You could have a function for loading lists from JSON files - something like

```py
# import json
def list_fromJsonFile(filename, printWarnings=False):
    try: 
        with open(filename, 'r') as f: retList = json.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        retList = []
        if printWarnings: print('Failed to load', repr(e))
    if not isinstance(retList, list): 
        if printWarnings: print('Returning as', [{'previous_data': type(retList)}])
        retList = [{'previous_data': retList}]
    return retList
```

With that, I don't see why this should cause any issues [in terms of JSON handling]:

```py
    def create_task():
        storageFilePath = 'taskstorage.json' # path to storage
        tasksList = list_fromJsonFile(storageFilePath) # load previous data

        taskDict = {
            'name': TaskNameEntry.get()
            'Group': GroupNameEntry.get()
            'Priority': PriorityEntry.get()
            'Start_Date': start_date_entry.get()
            'End_Date': end_date_entry.get()
            'Start_Time': start_time_entry.get()
            'end_time': end_time_entry.get()
        }

        with open(storageFilePath, 'w') as jsonfile:
            json.dump(
                tasksList+[taskDict], jsonfile, indent=4,
                default=lambda o: getattr(o, '__dict__', str(o))
            ) 
        messagebox.showinfo('eTasks', 'Task saved')
```

<sup>[ As far as I'm aware, the values returned by `Entry.get()` are JSON-serializable, but still I passed *`default=lambda o: getattr(o, '__dict__', str(o))`* to [`.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) just in case, so that any non-serializable values are converted to dictionaries (or, if that's not possible, to string).]</sup>

Since you're saving *`tasksList+[taskDict]`*, you should not be losing any of the old data; and then, if you want to

> be able to call each task separately by name

You can load the saved list and convert that list to a [nested] dictionary keyed to `name`.

```py
tasks_list = list_fromJsonFile('taskstorage.json', printWarnings=True)
tasks_by_name = {t['name']: t for t in tasks_list if isinstance(t,dict) and 'name' in t}
```

<sup>**Note that if there are any duplicate `name`s, only the last task `t` of each `name` will remain in `tasks_by_name`.**</sup>

You can loop through the task dictionaries with `for task in tasks_list`, or get a task (named `task_name='task_1'`, for example) with `tasks_by_name[task_name]`, or `tasks_by_name['task_1']`, or [if you're not sure that there's a task with that name] **`tasks_by_name.get(task_name)`**.

---

If you don't want to have to load previous data every time you want to add a new task, I suggest [using CSV files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for storage instead.

```py
# import os
# import pandas as pd

    def create_task():
        storageFilePath = 'taskstorage.csv' # path to storage

        # taskDict = {...} ## AS BEFORE

        wHed = not os.path.isfile(storageFilePath)
        pd.DataFrame([taskDict]).to_csv(storageFilePath,mode='a',index=False,header=wHed)
        messagebox.showinfo('eTasks',f'Task saved to {os.path.abspath(storageFilePath)}')
```

<sup>[ Passing `mode='a'` appends to file instead of over-writing old data, and the `wHed` flag is for adding the headers row if a new file is created. ]</sup>

In this case, a function like `list_fromJsonFile` is no longer needed as the tasks can be loaded with [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```py
# tasks_by_name = pd.read_csv('taskstorage.csv').set_index('name').to_dict('index')#maybe
tasks_list = pd.read_csv('taskstorage.csv').to_dict('records')
tasks_by_name = {t['name']: t for t in tasks_list if isinstance(t,dict) and 'name' in t}
```

---

> dbm overwrote the previous data

From what I understand, you can only have one instance of each key in a dbm file. You could make the name *part* of the keys to keep from overwriting other tasks [as long as the names are unique].

```py
    def create_task():
        with dbm.open('taskstorage.db' , 'c') as taskdb:
            tName = TaskNameEntry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} name']=tName
            taskdb[f'{tName} Group']=GroupNameEntry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} Priority']=PriorityEntry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} Start_Date']=start_date_entry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} End_Date']=end_date_entry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} Start_Time']=start_time_entry.get()
            taskdb[f'{tName} end_time']=end_time_entry.get()
        messagebox.showinfo('eTasks', 'Task saved')
```